# How to set Barriers route parameters

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, routing, feature-layer

I am using the ArcGIS Javascript3.22 API routeTask to determine the route around polygon barriers.

How do I properly define the polygon barriers?

What I have tried is:

```
  routeTask = new RouteTask("https://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World");
  routeParams = new RouteParameters();
  routeParams.polygonBarriers =  new FeatureSet("http://arcgis-geog865-942335747.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/arcgis/rest/services/RoadLimit_feature_server/FeatureServer/0");
```

But, when I include the last line above (routeParams.polygonBarriers...) in my code the page stop's working.

Answer (score 1):

You can only create a `FeatureSet` pasing a JSON as a parameter, not a URL. That's the reason your code fails. You can see it in the [FeatureSet-Documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featureset-amd.html)

So you have to query the FeatureService, get back the results as JSON, and then you can pass it to the `RouteParameters`. Something like this (NOT TESTED)

```
routeTask = new RouteTask("https://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/Route/NAServer/Route_World");
routeParams = new RouteParameters();
routeParams.polygonBarriers =  new FeatureSet("http://arcgis-geog865-942335747.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/arcgis/rest/services/RoadLimit_feature_server/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&f=json");
```

You can also initialized a `FeatureSet` and then push the barriers as graphics:

```
routeParams.polygonBarriers = new FeatureSet();
routeParams.polygonBarriers.features.push(
    map.graphics.add(
        new Graphic(geometry?, symbol?, attributes?, infoTemplate?);
);
```

In the documentation for the [RouteParameters](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/routeparameters-amd.html) you have more info an example in case you need it.